# Whitespace appearing after first figure and before text but not after second figure and before text

Tags: graphics, floats, white-space

I am using the twosided book document class, and I am trying to place two figures with text after each figure. I am noticing that after the first figure, the text is placed at the bottom of the page with a large amount of white space separating the figure and the text. However, after the second image, there is no such white space and the text neatly hugs the bottom of second figure. Is there any way to replicate this behaviour on the first figure?

Please note that I am using the `float` package here to force figure placement, I noticed that the standard `!htp` does not achieve the proper text placement. But if there is a solution that works with `!htp`, then I am absolutely open to it.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{caption-a}
\end{figure}

testing

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{caption-b}
\end{figure}

testing

\end{document}
```

which produces the following document:

[image: figure and text 1]

[image: figure and text 2]

EDIT:

It was suggested that the `[H]` should be avoided, and so when I convert to `[ht]` options, the ordering of the figure and the text is not as intended.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{caption-a}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{caption-b}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

which results in the following document:

[image: edited page 1]
[image: edited page 2]

Inserting a `\clearpage` after the text in the first MWE worked for me.

Comment: `twoside` also activates `\flushbottom` for vertically justification of pages. I would recommend not to use option `[H]` (but no option or something like `[htp]`), to avoid the issue after adding more text. But maybe you want `\raggedbottom` (which I do not recommend for books) or just a `\clearpage` before the second figure.

Comment: Your images are to big that can be fit on one page. Try to reduce the size of the first one to `width=0.8` and than replace placeholder `[H]` with `[!ht]`. Please consider @cabohah comments above.

Comment: Thanks @cabobah, I tried avoiding the `[H]` option as you suggested, but this causes issues with figure-text ordering (see edit). I then tried your suggestion with `[H]` and the `\clearpage` command, and this works as intended, thanks!